# How do I display the language settings (Site language field) on the user registration form?

Tags: 8, users

I'm trying to display the user's language settings field on the registration page, but no success so far.

I've tried using a template (form--user-register-form.html.twig). This works for other fields, like mail, name, but I don't know how to access the language setting field.

I also tried form_alter (both in the theme and module MODULE_user_register_form_alter), and set `$form['language']['#access'] = true;` This hook doesn't seem to work at all, nothing happens when I try to use it (print out variables for example).

Comment: Did you check "Enable translation" on /admin/config/people/accounts? Then, did you go to /admin/config/people/accounts/form-display and make sure the "Language code" field was moved out of "Disabled"? Also, did you mean to name your twig file form--user-register-from.html.twig or form--user-register-**form**.html.twig

Comment: I checked "Enable translation" (what does that do btw?), but it didn't make any difference.

The language code is also enabled. I also don't know what's the difference between the language code field and the language settings field though.

The 'from' was just a typo.

Interestingly, I could set the `$form['language']['#access'] = true;` in the twig template, and it made the language settings box visible, but the select is missing from it. I wonder if it's maybe a permission issue (something that the anonymous user doesn't have, but I couldn't find anything).

Comment: The only way I could display it, if I give the Anonymous user the permission to 'Administer users'. That is not really a solution, but that seems to be the permission that makes it available.

Comment: If the D7 solution is any guide, I think you need a form alter hook to change the #access value for the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but there's a current issue opened on Drupal core for this here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3163758